# Trying to install ruby 1.9.3 on Alpine 3.4 fails

Tags: ruby, rvm, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build an alpine:3.4 image with ruby 1.9.3 using rvm but I get the following error message:

```
io.o: In function `linux_iocparm_len':
/home/travis/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551/io.c:8086: undefined reference to `_IOC_SIZE'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:165: recipe for target 'miniruby' failed
```

I've been able to install both ruby 2.2 and 2.3 without any problems, but had no luck with 1.9.3

The command I used for 2.3 is

```
rvm install 2.3.0 --disable-binary --movable --autolibs=0
```

I've installed rvm from https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Comment: I've now come past the  "undefined reference to `_IOC_SIZE'" problem by patching io.c. This unfortunately only took me to the next problem which is this error

Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of ~.rvm/log/1475229205_ruby-1.9.3-p551/install.log
 from /home/travis/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/fileutils.rb:1515:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
 from /home/travis/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/fileutils.rb:1529:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
 from /home/travis/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/fileutils.rb:1513:in `fu_each_src_dest'

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by backporting the same conditionals the latest version of Ruby has for `_IOC_SIZE` to `ruby/io.c`. I was able to compile and install afterwards.

The pull request is https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1485, the fix is https://github.com/rallen-temp/ruby/commit/cbaaf34a0aa3c90f6a43d4383258c14a803bed12.

I also referenced this issue in the PR. Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this.

Comment: You can see a Dockerfile with the patch applied here: https://github.com/silver-mx/docker-alpine-rbenv/blob/master/Dockerfile